# Speeding up Views 2?

Tags: views, 6

How can I speed up my complex views? I don't want to remove functionality from my views to speed them up. Some of my views have 5 lefts joins. Is there anything I can do to optimize these queries?

Here's an example: http://i27.lulzimg.com/214ce7e242.png

Here's another one: http://i27.lulzimg.com/5c1d52ab2d.png

Comment: OK, some of your view have 5 joins... but are they slow? How much time does it take the full page to render in the browser, and how much of that time is spent in MySQL? I'm asking because other methods are often more effective to improve performance.

Comment: Here's an example http://i27.lulzimg.com/214ce7e242.png

Comment: Ouch... ok, that *is* slow. The first thing I notice is `LIKE ('%%')`. What does that do?

Comment: The first thing which shows up is term_data.name you should better use a tid filter.

Comment: I have no idea what LIKE ('%%') does

Comment: Wow. tid filter made a huge difference.

Comment: I think that `LIKE ('%%')` is coming from a misconfigured filter w/ an empty argument.

Comment: MPD, you are right. I removed it

Comment: I added a second image. This page is faster but I still want to speed it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try installing [DB Tuner](http://drupal.org/project/db_tuner) and/or run [mysqltuner.pl](http://mysqltuner.pl/mysqltuner.pl) and experiment with the suggestions.

**Edit to address the comments.**

In addition to trying to optimize the database itself, you can also copy/paste the SQL that Views generates and run the query manually with an [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html).  This may shed some light on why the query is taking a while to run.  You can then edit the view as needed, and potentially add some indexes that the above tools may not have identified.